# How to check if flow<PagingData<Item>> contains specific item?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, android-paging

I have a Flow of PagingData and I need to check if this flow contains specific Item value.
I know that I cant collect it by `.collectAsLazyPagingItems().itemSnapshotList.items`, but it is possible only in `@Composable`. How can I do it or though get the List of Item?
I have tried like this:

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            itemsFlow.onEach { 
                it.map { item ->
                    if (item == myItem) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }.collect()
        }
```

but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`PagingData` does not hold any state, it's only used to hook up paging to something that can actually collect and present the state, like `PagingDataAdapter` or in `LazyPagingItems` using the method you've already found.

Another way to think about it is that it is impossible to inspect whether a paginated list contains an item, without first loading all the items, and currently the only way to realize the state in Paging is by collecting it in the UI layer.

Similarly, `PagingData.map` does not eagerly load the entire list, it operates incrementally as items are loaded in to be displayed in the UI. So you can use it to check if / when a specific item is loaded, but you cannot use it to search the list since it only runs as items are loaded for the UI.

Comment: I did this operation on UI layer instead of VM. Thanks for help.